# Understanding the label helper method, specifically the "for" property of the rendered HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, label

I have a strongly typed partial view `CheckBox.ascx` that renders a checkbox. This is used by another partial view that renders a list of checkboxes using `CheckBox.ascx`.

I am having problems figuring out how to use the `Html.Label` helper method to get labels working correctly, i.e. setting the `label` `for` property to be the `id` of the related checkbox.

My view markup for the checkbox looks like this:
(I'm using non-sequential list binding as described under [Non-Sequential Indices](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx))

```
<%= Html.CheckBox(string.Format("checkBoxes[{0}].Checked", Model.Id), Model.Checked)%>
```

The complexity here is that my checkbox ID will be mangled - `[`, `]`, `.` characters replaced with `_`.

Can the `Html.Label` helper method help me here?

Comment: Have you considered altering your `CheckBox.ascx` so that it renders a label and a checkbox together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to manually code the `label` element...

```
<label for="<%= string.Format("checkBoxes_{0}__Checked", Model.Id)%>"><%= Html.Encode(Model.Label)%></label>
```

(noting that the `.`, `[` and `]` characters in the checkbox name get rendered as underscores)